# Where clause in sql query remove also null values

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have these tables:

'Users'

```
id  email                name                 last_access
1   luca@gmail.com       Luca Pluto           2012-10-05 17:21:22.0
2   pippo@gmail.com      Irene Pippo          2012-10-05 17:22:25.0
```

'Nets_permissions'

```
user_id         network_id  perm
1               1234        3
1               1235        1
2               1235        3
```

I've written this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n
ON u.id = n.user_id
WHERE n.network_id=1234 AND n.perm <> 3
```

because I want users that already have a permission for network_id  (1234) , but also users that don't have a permission for the network_id. In other words I would have this result query:

```
2    null    null
```

because the user Luca Pluto with id=1, for the net 1234, have perm=3 so I want left out. Instead, the user Irene Pippo with id=2 doesn't have any permission on the 1234 net. So it's row must have net_id and perm set to null.

My query result is empty. I don't know why. Without the clause n.perm <> 3 seems to work well, but after also the null value are left out, not only the rws with perm=3.

I've also tried in this way:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select * from nets_permissions WHERE network_id=1234) as n on u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE n.perm <> 3
```

but it doesn't work. without the WHERE clause all works. After no. The result query is empty.

How I can resolve this problem? I need that the perm column is a value or null, I can't remove this column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(select * from nets_permissions WHERE network_id=1234) as n on u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE (n.perm <> 3 or n.perm is NULL)
```

Here [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) there is a expanation of the treatment of NULL values in MySQL

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Many SQL dialect use a special trinary logic with `NULL` the third possible value additional to `true` and `false`.

Anything compared to `NULL` results to `NULL` which in turn is handled as `false`.

So `x = null` will result in `false` for all `x`, just as `x != null`

If you want to include `NULL` values in the result you have to add special handling for that (Oracle syntax):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n
ON u.id = n.user_id
WHERE n.network_id=1234 
AND (n.perm <> 3 or n.perm is not null)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. The result query is `1 Luca Pluto 3`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm
FROM 
    users as u 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    nets_permissions as n ON u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE 
    n.network_id = 1234 and n.perm <> 3
    or
    n.network_id <> 1234
    or
    n.network_id is null
```

Comment: Also the result of this query is empty. Is like if the left outer join doesn't working...

Comment: @sharkbait - Get rid of the `WHERE` entirely and put the whole thing into the `JOIN` condition. This still has the same problem. You only need a `WHERE` here if you are trying to filter on `users`

Comment: @sharkbait I did read again your question and rewrote the query. Not quite sure I understand.

Comment: Nothing. Also this doesn't works... I understand the problem and the possible solution, but all your answers doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I like users that user the "JOIN" syntax. It has additional benefit, aside from making the code easier to read, that people don't realize.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.perm
FROM users as u LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n
ON u.id = n.user_id
AND n.network_id=1234 
WHERE COALESCE(n.perm,-1) <> 3
```

Comment: No it doesn't work. What if I do a subtraction (-) of queries? First I obtain the entire list of users and after I subtract the users that have perm=3 in the net_id=1234 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? 2 null null is not showing up?

Comment: The result query is 1 Luca Pluto null, 2 Irene Pippo null. The second row is perfect. But I don't want the first because Luca Pluto have perm=3 in the net_id=1234

Comment: gotya. replace the AND n.perm <> 3 with WHERE COALESCE(n.perm,-1) <> 3.